# O que é Neologismo e qual a diferença dele com Estrangeirismo?

Tags: linguística

O que é Neologismo e qual a diferença dele com Estrangeirismo? Quando ocorre este efeito ou efeitos?

---

What is "Neologismo" and what a difference it with "Estrangeirismo"? When this occurs effect or effects?

Answer (score 3):

`Estrangeirismo`: linguistic phenomenon that includes a word or expression from another language in our vocabulary: Show, design, feedback.

`Neologismo`: linguistic phenomenon that creates or adapts words into Portuguese.

> Beijo pouco, falo menos ainda. Mas invento palavras Que traduzem a
>   ternura mais funda E mais cotidiana. **Inventei, por exemplo, o verbo**
>   **teadorar**. Intransitivo: Teadoro, Teodora [Bandeira, Manuel]

[Fonte](http://www.brasilescola.com/gramatica/diferencas-entre-neologismo-estrangeirismo.htm)

Comment: Good answer, edit and translate to Portuguese (don't remove English answer). Thanks!